# Could not find active_utils-1.0.5 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My gemfile  contains
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.8'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

#gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'execjs'
#gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'therubyracer', ' 0.9.10'
gem 'rubycas-client', '2.3.9'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

#gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'devise'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
gem 'spree', '1.2.0'
gem 'spree_usa_epay'
gem 'spree_skrill'
gem 'spree_gateway', :git => 'git://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git', :branch => "1-     1-stable" # make sure to include after spree
gem 'spree_i18n', :git => 'git://github.com/spree/spree_i18n.git'
gem 'ruport' , :git => 'git://github.com/ChrisLusted/ruport.git', :branch => 'ruby19-compat'
gem 'spree_flexi_variants', :git=>'git@github.com:jsqu99/spree_flexi_variants.git'
```

===========================================================================================

```
And if I do bundle install it will give ouput
Using rake (10.0.3) 
Using i18n (0.6.1) 
Using multi_json (1.5.0) 
Using activesupport (3.2.8) 
Using builder (3.0.4) 
Using activemodel (3.2.8) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.4) 
Using rack (1.4.1) 
Using rack-cache (1.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sprockets (2.1.3) 
Using actionpack (3.2.8) 
Using mime-types (1.19) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.12) 
Using mail (2.4.4) 
Using actionmailer (3.2.8) 
Using active_utils (1.0.5) 
Using json (1.7.5) 
Using money (5.0.0) 
Using nokogiri (1.5.5) 
Using activemerchant (1.28.0) 
Using arel (3.0.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.35) 
Using activerecord (3.2.8) 
Using activeresource (3.2.8) 
Using acts_as_list (0.1.4) 
Using gyoku (1.0.0) 
Using akami (1.2.0) 
Using multi_xml (0.5.1) 
Using httparty (0.8.3) 
Using uuidtools (2.1.3) 
Using aws-sdk (1.3.9) 
Using bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1) 
Using cancan (1.6.7) 
Using carrierwave (0.7.1) 
Using cocaine (0.4.2) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.4.0) 
Using execjs (1.4.0) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2) 
Using rdoc (3.12) 
Using thor (0.16.0) 
Using railties (3.2.8) 
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2) 
Using color (1.4.2) 
Using bundler (1.3.5) 
Using rails (3.2.8) 
Using deface (0.9.1) 
Using orm_adapter (0.4.0) 
Using warden (1.2.1) 
Using devise (2.1.2) 
Using fastercsv (1.5.5) 
Using ffaker (1.12.1) 
Using highline (1.6.11) 
Using hirb (0.7.0) 
Using httpi (2.0.0) 
Using jquery-rails (2.1.4) 
Using kaminari (0.14.1) 
Using libv8 (3.3.10.4) 
Using mysql2 (0.3.11) 
Using nested_set (1.7.0) 
Using nori (2.0.0) 
Using paperclip (2.8.0) 
Using transaction-simple (1.4.0.2) 
Using pdf-writer (1.1.8) 
Using polyamorous (0.5.0) 
Using rabl (0.6.5) 
Using ransack (0.7.2) 
Using rmagick (2.13.1) 
Using rubycas-client (2.3.9) 
Using ruport (1.6.3) 
Using sass (3.2.3) 
Using sass-rails (3.2.5) 
Using wasabi (3.0.0) 
Using savon (2.0.0) 
Using select2-rails (0.0.9) 
Using state_machine (1.1.2) 
Using stringex (1.3.3) 
Using spree_core (1.2.0) 
Using spree_api (1.2.0) 
Using spree_cmd (1.2.0) 
Using spree_dash (1.2.0) 
Using spree_promo (1.2.0) 
Using spree_sample (1.2.0) 
Using spree (1.2.0) 
Using spree_flexi_variants (1.0.0) from git@github.com:jsqu99/spree_flexi_variants.git (at master) 
Using spree_gateway (1.1.0) from git://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git (at 1-1-stable) 
Using spree_i18n (1.0.0) from git://github.com/spree/spree_i18n.git (at master) 
Using spree_skrill (1.0.2) 
Using spree_usa_epay (1.0.2) 
Using therubyracer (0.9.10) 
Using uglifier (1.3.0) 
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

But It gives error i.e.Ruby (Rack) application could not be started

Error Messages
Could not find active_utils-1.0.5 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

But that gem is already installed install and present. Then Why this error coming

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your gems are installed under different gemset or your bundler is installing it in a different location. To identify that, try starting ruby server using "bundle exec " . This will identify whether, bundler is installing it in a different location than your app path.eg: bundle exec rails server

Comment: I found the solution , I used bundle intsall --path=vendor/cache

Answer (score 0):

I used 
    bundle install --path vendor/cache